# z-index in css don't work in my main menue

Tags: css, z-index

I have a problem with the "z-index" property in css.

```
  <div class="mobil__navigation">
        <div class="toggle" id="toggle">
            <div class="toggle-line"></div>
            <div class="toggle-line"></div>
            <div class="toggle-line"></div>
          </div>
          <img src="ressources/images/Logo.png"/>
        </div>
        <nav class="mobil__links">
          <ol>
            <li class="mt-0"><a href="#">Mülltrennung</a><span class="mobil_menue_arrow"><img src="ressources/images/arrows.svg"></span></li>
            <li><a href="#">Umweltbewusstsein</a><span class="mobil_menue_arrow"><img src="ressources/images/arrows.svg"></span></li>
            <li><a href="#">Nachhaltigkeit</a><span class="mobil_menue_arrow"><img src="ressources/images/arrows.svg"></span></li>
            <li><a href="#">Teste dein Wissen</a><span class="mobil_menue_arrow"><img src="ressources/images/arrows.svg"></span></li>
          </ol>
        </nav>

        <div class="main__description">
          <div class="headline">
            <h1>Was ist Müll eigentlich?</h1>
            <div class="headline_line"></div>
          </div>
          </h1>
          <p>Abfall ist für uns all das, was wir nicht mehr gebrauchen können. Allerdings ist die<br/>
            Entscheidung, was noch brauchbar ist oder was schon unbrauchbar, also Müll ist,<br/>
            von jedem selbst abhängig und oft individuell sehr unterschiedlich.<br/>
            Grundsätzlich versteht man unter Abfall bzw. Müll  die <b>Reste</b>, die bei der <b>Zubereitung oder Herstellung</b><br/>
            von etwas entstehen.</p>
        </div>
```

and my css:

```
    display: none;
    width:50%;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 9px 21px -8px rgba(0,0,0,0.46);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 9px 21px -8px rgba(0,0,0,0.46);
    box-shadow: 0px 9px 21px -8px rgba(0,0,0,0.46);
    padding-top: 35px;
    padding-bottom: 35px;
    position:relative;
    z-index:2;
  }
  .main__description {
      margin-top:0;
      position: relative;
      top:160px;
      left:50%;
      transform: translateX(-50%);
      z-index:-1;
  }
```

Does anyone know, the my class which is called "mobil__links" is not above the class which is called "main__description"?

I'M looking forward to hwar from you ;=)

Comment: Hi, I think there may be a couple of little bits missing from your example code - the end of the HTML and the start of the CSS? Could you put them in as I'm guessing the CSS refers to the mobil but I can't be sure. Then I'll have another look.

Comment: Hi, i have upload my code on codepen.io :)
https://codepen.io/wreter/pen/oNLBbar

Comment: Meanwhile I had a look and posted an answer!

Answer (score 0):

The main problem seems to be that although the menu is given z-index 2 and the text is given z-index -1 they are both positioned relatively.

So, let's keep the main at position:relative and instead position the menu. It already has a z-index greater than main so if we can get it to not interfere with the position of main it should show up on top of it. We set its position to absolute. This means it will be positioned in the natural flow (in this case at the top as we have nothing above it) but it wont affect the position of any element coming after it, so the main text can tuck underneath.

Note: for a menu when the user is scrolling and so on you may want to consider position: fixed so that it doesn't disappear as they scroll down - it depends on your particular use case.

In this snippet I have made a couple of other alterations - see the comments - and aligned the elements so we can more clearly see the hierarchy.

```css
 .mobil__links {
    rdisplay: none;/* taken out just for the test */
    width:50%;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 9px 21px -8px rgba(0,0,0,0.46);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 9px 21px -8px rgba(0,0,0,0.46);
    box-shadow: 0px 9px 21px -8px rgba(0,0,0,0.46);
    padding-top: 35px;
    padding-bottom: 35px;
    position:relative;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:2;
  }
  .main__description {
      margin-top:0;
      position: relative;
      top:160px;
      left:50%;
      transform: translateX(-50%);
      z-index:-1;
  }
```

```html
  <div class="mobil__navigation">
    <div class="toggle" id="toggle">
      <div class="toggle-line"></div>
         <div class="toggle-line"></div>
            <div class="toggle-line"></div>
      </div>
      <img src="ressources/images/Logo.png"/>
   </div>
   <nav class="mobil__links">
      <ol>
        <li class="mt-0"><a href="#">Mülltrennung</a><span class="mobil_menue_arrow"><img src="ressources/images/arrows.svg"></span></li>
        <li><a href="#">Umweltbewusstsein</a><span class="mobil_menue_arrow"><img src="ressources/images/arrows.svg"></span></li>
        <li><a href="#">Nachhaltigkeit</a><span class="mobil_menue_arrow"><img src="ressources/images/arrows.svg"></span></li>
        <li><a href="#">Teste dein Wissen</a><span class="mobil_menue_arrow"><img src="ressources/images/arrows.svg"></span></li>
      </ol>
   </nav>

   <div class="main__description">
     <div class="headline">
       <h1>Was ist Müll eigentlich?</h1>
         <div class="headline_line"></div>
     </div>
          <!-- spurious h1 </h1> -->
     <p>Abfall ist für uns all das, was wir nicht mehr gebrauchen können. Allerdings ist die<br/>
            Entscheidung, was noch brauchbar ist oder was schon unbrauchbar, also Müll ist,<br/>
            von jedem selbst abhängig und oft individuell sehr unterschiedlich.<br/>
            Grundsätzlich versteht man unter Abfall bzw. Müll  die <b>Reste</b>, die bei der <b>Zubereitung oder Herstellung</b><br/>
            von etwas entstehen.
      </p>
    </div>
```

Comment: I have copy and paste the code in my project, it doesn't work...

Comment: What are you seeing? ie what does doesn't work mean? Also the snippet in the answer is not designed to be copied exactly but to display what can work. Look at the absolute and relative positioning of your menu and your main text

Comment: Nothing has been changed, my menue is not above the text.

Comment: Can I see the code you are using - is the codepen updated to make the menu absolutely positioned?

Comment: Yes, codepen is up-to-date.
https://codepen.io/wreter/pen/oNLBbar

Comment: Where is the code that senses a click on the menu (and so I assume changes it from display:none). Is it in the imported script because that doesn't seem to be being imported into the codepen.

Comment: @A Haworth, I have found the Error, "mobil__links", needs a background-color ;)
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You commanded on two lines that the `.mobil__links` should have `display:none;`.
So it obviously didn't show up in the first place, but I think that was your intention. But for this example, I've commented it out.

The `.mobil__links` had the `position:relative;` property. The `desktop__navigation` also had that property, meaning it would push the `.mobil__links` away. So: adding `position:absolute;` to the `.mobil__links` would fix that problem.

Now, you still need to define the position (top, left). Adding that to the `.mobile__links` would give it the right position. I've added `top:0px;` and `left:0px;` to make it show up in the top left corner of your screen.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
/*.mobil__links {
  display: none;
}*/
.social {
  width:calc(100% - 138px);
  display:flex;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  padding-right:138px;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  background-color: #C2C38E;
}
.social ol {
  display:flex;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.social ol li {
  padding-right: 5px;
  border-right: 1px solid white;
}
.social ol li:last-child {
  padding-right: 0px;
  border-right: 0px solid black;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
.social ol li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color:White;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: Roboto;
}
.desktop__navigation {
  width:100%;
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 47px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 6px 5px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.63);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 6px 5px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.63);
  box-shadow: 0px 6px 5px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.63);
}
.desktop__navigation ol {
  padding-right: 138px;
  padding-left: 138px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  margin:0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.desktop__navigation ol li a {
  color:black;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.desktop__navigation ol li a img {
  height:150px;
  width:180px;
}
.mobil__navigation {
  display: none;
}
.toggle {
  display: none;
}
.mobil_menue_arrow {
  display: none;
}
.main__description {
  margin:0 auto;
  width:60%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top:160px;
}
.headline {
  position: relative;
  width:400px;
  margin:0 auto;
}
.headline_line {
  position: absolute;
  bottom:-10px;
  left:5%;
  height:30px;
  background-image: url("../ressources/images/unterstrich.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 63%;
  z-index: 1;
}
.main__description h1 {
  position: relative;
  z-index:2;
  font-family:A little sunshine;
  font-size: 50px;
}
.main__description p {
  font-family:Roboto;
  font-size: 20px
}
@media (max-width:1400px) {
  /*Helpingclasses*/
  .d-block {
    display: block !important;
  }
  .mt-0 {
    margin-top: 0 !important;
  }
  .desktop__navigation {
    display: none;
  }
  .toggle {
    display: block;
    margin-left:20px;
    position: absolute;
  }
  .toggle-line {
    margin-top:10px;
    height:5px;
    background-color: #C2C38E;
    width:40px;
  }
  .social {
    padding: 0;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    width:100%;
    padding-right: 50px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  .social ol li a {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-size: 11px;
  }
  .mobil__links {
    /*display: none;*/
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    width:50%;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 9px 21px -8px rgba(0,0,0,0.46);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 9px 21px -8px rgba(0,0,0,0.46);
    box-shadow: 0px 9px 21px -8px rgba(0,0,0,0.46);
    padding-top: 35px;
    padding-bottom: 35px;
    z-index:2;
    background-color:white;
  }
  .mobil__links ol {
    width:100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
  }
  .mobil__links li {
    display: flex;
    margin-top: 30px;
  }
  .mobil__links li span {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    position: absolute;
    right:30px;
  }
  .mobil__links ol li a {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    font-family: Roboto;
    padding-left: 15px;
  }
  .mobil__links ol li a img {
    height:100px;
  }
  .mobil__navigation {
    display:flex;
    padding-top: 13px;
    padding-bottom: 13px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 6px 25px -3px rgba(0,0,0,0.57);
    -moz-box-shadow: 3px 6px 25px -3px rgba(0,0,0,0.57);
     box-shadow: 3px 6px 25px -3px rgba(0,0,0,0.57);
  }
  .mobil__navigation img {
    width: 56px;
    height:46px;
    display:block;
    margin:0 auto;
  }
  .mobil_menue_arrow img{
    display: block;
    height:12px;
    width:17px;
  }
  .main__description {
      margin-top:0;
      position: relative;
      top:160px;
      left:50%;
      transform: translateX(-50%);
      z-index:-1;
  }
  .main__description h1 {
      font-size: 23px;
  }
  .headline {
    width:171.5px;
  }
  .main__description p{
    font-size: 13px;
    font-family: Roboto;
  }
  .headline_line {
    position: absolute;
    bottom:5px;
    left:0%;
    height:30px;
    background-image: url("../ressources/images/unterstrich.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 30%;
    height:5px;
    z-index: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
      <title>Unsere Seite</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css"/>
    </head>

    <body>
      <div class="social">
        <ol>
            <li><a href="instagram.com">Instagram</a></li>
            <li><a href="instagram.com">Facebook</a></li>
        </ol>
      </div>
        <nav class="desktop__navigation">
          <ol>
            <li><a href="#">Mülltrennung</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Umweltbewusstsein</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="ressources/images/Logo.png"/></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Nachhaltigkeit</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Teste dein Wissen</a></li>
          </ol>
        </nav>

        <div class="mobil__navigation">
        <div class="toggle" id="toggle">
            <div class="toggle-line"></div>
            <div class="toggle-line"></div>
            <div class="toggle-line"></div>
          </div>
          <img src="ressources/images/Logo.png"/>
        </div>
        <nav class="mobil__links">
          <ol>
            <li class="mt-0"><a href="#">Mülltrennung</a><span class="mobil_menue_arrow"><img src="ressources/images/arrows.svg"></span></li>
            <li><a href="#">Umweltbewusstsein</a><span class="mobil_menue_arrow"><img src="ressources/images/arrows.svg"></span></li>
            <li><a href="#">Nachhaltigkeit</a><span class="mobil_menue_arrow"><img src="ressources/images/arrows.svg"></span></li>
            <li><a href="#">Teste dein Wissen</a><span class="mobil_menue_arrow"><img src="ressources/images/arrows.svg"></span></li>
          </ol>
        </nav>

        <div class="main__description">
          <div class="headline">
            <h1>Was ist Müll eigentlich?</h1>
            <div class="headline_line"></div>
          </div>
          </h1>
          <p>Abfall ist für uns all das, was wir nicht mehr gebrauchen können. Allerdings ist die<br/>
            Entscheidung, was noch brauchbar ist oder was schon unbrauchbar, also Müll ist,<br/>
            von jedem selbst abhängig und oft individuell sehr unterschiedlich.<br/>
            Grundsätzlich versteht man unter Abfall bzw. Müll  die <b>Reste</b>, die bei der <b>Zubereitung oder Herstellung</b><br/>
            von etwas entstehen.</p>
        </div>
        <script src="js/script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

try to change position to absolute or relative

Comment: I have already change the position on every element,but its don't work.
With "it's doesn't work" i mean, thats nothing changed